# free function triggers breakpoint c

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

When I try to free my array it gives me a "heap corruption detected" error. My program is a bit complicated so I simplified it to the following:

```
char ***courses = (char ***)malloc(1, sizeof(char**));
courses[0] = (char**)malloc(2, sizeof(char*));
courses[0][1] = (char*)calloc(5, sizeof(char));
courses[0][0] = "aaaa";
courses[0][1] = "aaaa";
free(courses[0][1]);
```

When I run the simplified form it doesn't give me the "heap corruption detected" error but it says "program has triggered a breakpoint". What am I doing wrong? All theses errors are causes by the "free" function.

EDIT: I forgot to add the lines where I allocate memory for courses[0][1]. Added the 3rd line of code.

Comment: void **malloc(n**sizeof(datatype))  This is the definition of malloc right ?

Comment: Did OP mean `calloc()` - there are 2 args?

Comment: It would also help if you post a *complete* example so that it would be easier to advise possible solutions. As it is, the answer is "what you are doing is wrong" which may not be of much help to you. What you pass is to `free()` is likely going to be cause for heap corruption. But your malloc() calls don't look right and you may have other problems too.

Comment: Your last line of code is equivalent to `free("aaaa");` which is obviously illegal.

Answer (score 1):

```
courses[0][1] = "aaaa";
```

`courses[0][1]` is pointing at to *string literal*, which is not something you allocated. So [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) results.

The rule for using `free()` is very simple: you only `free()` a pointer which was returned by `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()` function or a `NULL` pointer.
Passing anything else is invalid.

*C11, 7.22.3.3, free function states*

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
>   deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is
>   a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not
>   match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or
>   if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Comment: I forgot to add a line. Please look at my code now and tell me what's wrong.

Comment: 1) Your `malloc()` calls don't do what you think they do: it takes only one argument. See the [manual of malloc()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). 2) `courses[0][1] = "aaaa";` this overwrites  the pointer that was returned from `malloc()`. You probably want to use `strcpy()`: `strcpy(courses[0][1], "aaaa");`